# url link is too long to fit in one line Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How to avoid break in long url link sent through Spring MVC web app? It is a redirect url sent to email box in case of reset password request

http://man-01668:9090/HDCdemo/demoservice/portal/resetpassword.htm?pfpc=tMgmMyBhpVRi1pZq&redirect_url=http://localhost:8080/HDCdemo/demoservice/portal/myprofile.htm?_flowId=citizenportal/myprofile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an obvious answer, but: make the URL shorter.

Option 1) use a url shortener such as [bit.ly](http://bit.ly)

Option 2) implement your own URL shortener, using, for example, an app like [Yourls](http://yourls.org/).

Option 3) remove some of the items from the URL by storing them in your database; for example, if you have a unique ID for the user, you can record in the DB what their redirect URL should be, so you don't need to put it into the URL.